# How to access the class RegistryKey?

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

In the last few days, I tried to access regedit using c#.

The class RegistryKey is not defined after I added using `Microsoft.Win32`.

Can you help me?

#### Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace TMREAddons
{
    public class RegEdit
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\MySQL AB\\MySQL Connector\\Net")
    }
}
```

This is a basic class library, nothing more than that.

The targetFramework is:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: That code compiles for me, other than missing a semicolon. Perhaps you're targeting an inappropriate framework, or need an extra package, e.g. Microsoft.Win32.Registry if you're targeting .NET Core?

Comment: @TheGeneral there is no reason I try to access this key, the main problem is that the class is not defined

Comment: @JonSkeet shell I upgrade my framework? can that be the problem?

Comment: We don't know which version of the framework you're currently targeting, so we can't really answer. I doubt that it's a matter of *upgrading* though. If you provide us the context we need, we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet what info do you need?

Comment: As I said: "We don't know which version of the framework you're currently targeting" - that's the info we need. Look in your project file.

Comment: @JonSkeet ```<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>``` this is the Target Framework

Comment: Right. It would be good to edit that into the question, as it's crucial information. I've added an answer, but it's still worth improving the question.

Comment: Hmm.. the edit is different to your comment. I thought it was targeting .NET Standard 2.0, but the question now says .NET Standard 2.1. I've updated my answer to match the question, but please take care when it comes to details like this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting `netstandard2.1` - which basically means "I want this to be able to run on any platform that's compatible with .NET Standard 2.1". Given that the Windows Registry *doesn't* exist on every .NET Standard 2.1 compatible platform, I'm not surprised at the error you're getting. (In general, I wouldn't expect anything from `Microsoft.Win32` to be supported in .NET Standard.)

You can add the [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry) as a dependency, and that should solve the compilation issue - although it will still fail if you run on a non-Windows platform, of course.